# Automating process that needs user interaction not working in Ubuntu using expect package

Tags: command-line, 20.04, package-management, background-process, expect

I want to automate the running of a process in Ubuntu using Expect.

The process that I have asks the user to insert "ok" and then ask them to insert a password.

I've created an Expect script to automate the operation

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn -ignore HUP /home/startclef.cmd

expect "ok"

send "ok\r"

sleep 5

expect "Please enter the password to decrypt the master seed"

sleep 5

send "pass_123\r"

sleep 5

interact

expect_background
```

I stored the above script in a file named `script.expect`

When I execute the script in this way

```
./script.expect
```

it's working perfectly, but I want to run the process in the background so I executed the script in this way:

```
./script.expect &
```

it returns an error

```
liner: function not supported in this terminal
```

Comment: Remove the `sleep 5`s. `expect` will wait on your behalf.

Comment: The error message comes  from `startclef.cmd`. It doesn't like the value of the `TERM` environment variable. Check it with `echo $TERM` on your terminal and inside `startclef.cmd`.

Comment: It's easier to have `expect` turn off echo, and prompt for the password itself.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76628037/7552

Comment: @waltinator please note that the script works if I execute it directly not with (&).
The issue appears just if I run the script in the background.

Comment: I want to run this process on the system startup which is why I want to make it automatic and run in the background